# Understanding Android Service behaviour

Tags: android, service

I  noticed today a peculiar behavior of Android Service which I was not aware of previously and I want to understand what is the purpose. After going through documentation, I can confirm that this is expected behavior but cannot understand the reasons behind this design.

> The service keeps running indefinitely in background until
>   `StopSelf()` is called OR the android system destroys it due to low
>   memory. It means the service keeps showing on the Running services page after it has completed executed its OnstartCommand() method.

I do not understand what is the purpose of this behaviour? I believe the service should stop once its `OnStartCommand` is executed. Why it has to keep running in background (or stay in memory if that's correct wording). Is it just because a new intent to start a service can be served faster instead of overhead of creating the service in memory from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android tends to keep things around.  Even after your app exits and the last activity is destroyed, the Linux process tends to stay alive until Android needs the memory.

[The official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) covers services pretty well.  Pay close attention to the two ways of running services: bound vs. started.  I find it strange that books don't cover services very well; the O'Reilly "Programming Android" book only gives them a third of a page!  The important thing to know is that activities aren't the only first-class citizens in Android; services are every bit as important.  Any time you want to "do stuff" that isn't logically contained within the lifecycle of a single activity, a service is probably the right thing to use.

Answer (score 1):

Services can also be bound to for inter process communication.  An IntentService does as you say with a Queue.  It services one intent at a time, and automatically stops the service when it's complete.  [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) has a nice overview of how services can be used, and the differences in how they can be started.